# Change Data Capture SSIS not picking changes

Tags: sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

I am trying to implement change data capture in SQL Server 2012. I enabled it at database and table level. when i try to update the table, CDC_CT captures the changes. However when i am using SSIS CDC components, it doesnt pick anything.

the version of SQL server is:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU10-GDR) (KB4057121) - 11.0.6615.2 (X64) 
    Jan  9 2018 21:26:48 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Can someone please guide?

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959201/change-data-capture-cdc-ssis-not-working

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with SP3 in sql server 2012. As soon as I installed SP4 this issue went away.